# Aborted software install - epson perfection 3200 on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, troubleshooting, scanner

I just upgraded to Windows 7 64-bit, and boy, this is  a challenge to get old hardware to work. I tried to install my software for my 3200 perfection **scanner** straight form autoplay. When it tried to install Epson scan, it said it couldn't because the version of software was incorrect. It is showing up in the Uninstall window, but it won't uninstall it. How do I fix this? I know about installing the programs in XP compatibility mode which is what I should have done.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just delete the installation directory, this will allow you to delete the entry in Add/Remove Programs. You need to find 64-bit drivers for your scanner, what you attempted to install, were likely 32-bit drivers if you have to use XP Compatibility mode to install the drivers.  My guess you don't even need the drivers to use the scanner the generic drivers should work.

Answer (score 1):

I know from experience that some old hardware (especially older printers) won't work even under compatibility mode. Usually the best option is just to accept the cost of upgrading the printer. Fortunately, printers are fairly cheap these days.

Even if you did manage to get the printer working under Windows 7, it would probably be very unreliable, or lack some functionality (double-sided printing etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply - but it is a scanner and not a printer - I found somebody who had a workaround for the driver, but I haven't fopund anything about the software yet.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to get it working without needing to purchase more hardware.